# How to solve given problem in optimum way

Tags: java

My doubt is i wrote code in java but it takes more time to executes .
question is given as

Given a number n, you have to find the sum of the sequence: f(0)+f(1)+...+f(n)
where f(n)=2∗n+f(n−1);n>0 and f(0)=0.

Since the sum can be really large print the answer modulo 10^9+7
Input
The first line of input contains a single integer t denoting the number of test cases

Each test case contains a single line of input containing a string of digits denoting n
Output
For each test case print a single line containing an integer denoting the sum.

I knows it's very basic question but problem is how to solve it for very big integer .

my code is

```
package com.company;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Find_the_sun {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int T=sc.nextInt();
        BigInteger []A=new BigInteger[T];

        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
             BigInteger b=sc.nextBigInteger();
             A[i]=b;

        }

        for(int i=0;i<T;i++)
        {
            BigInteger answer=BigInteger.ZERO;
            BigInteger cal=BigInteger.ZERO;
            for(BigInteger j=BigInteger.ZERO;j.compareTo(A[i])<=0;j=j.add(BigInteger.ONE))
            {
                BigInteger temp=BigInteger.valueOf((long) (7+Math.pow(10,9)));
                if(j.equals(BigInteger.valueOf(1000)))
                {
                    answer=(BigInteger) ((j.multiply(BigInteger.TWO)).add(answer));
                    cal=(BigInteger) cal.add(answer);
                }
                else {
                    answer = (BigInteger) (((j.multiply(BigInteger.TWO)).mod(temp)).add(answer.mod(temp)));
                    cal = (BigInteger) cal.add(answer);
                }
            }



            BigInteger temp=BigInteger.valueOf((long) (7+Math.pow(10,9)));
            if(cal.compareTo( temp)>=0)
            {
                BigInteger cal2= (BigInteger) (cal.mod(temp));
                System.out.println(cal2);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println(cal);
            }



        }

    }
}
```

thank you.

and quiz is over ,So don't mark it as use for quiz.

Comment: ( x1 + x2 ) % y == ( ( x1 % y ) + ( x2 % y ) ) % y == ( ( x1 % y ) + x2 ) % y

Comment: @ikegami yes ,but still error is "time limit exceeded"

Comment: Does it matter? Since all your code needs to be replaced to take advantage of the property I just identified, who cares if your existing code takes too long.

Comment: Besides, you said "problem is how to solve it for very big integer ."

Answer (score 2):

**Summary**

Use

```
M = 10^9 + 7

mod(a)    = a % 3M
mul(a, b) = ( a * b ) % 3M

r(n) = mul( mul( mod(n), mod(mod(n)+1) ), mod(mod(n)+2) ) / 3
```

This avoid looping, and this avoids `BigInteger`! As long as *n* fits in a `long`, all you need is `long`.

---

**Eliminating Iteration**

You provided this formula:

```
f(n=0) = 2*n
f(n>0) = 2*n + f(n−1)

s(n=0) = f(n) = 0
s(n>0) = f(n) + s(n-1)
```

But we want to find the result mod ( 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 ). So it's really

```
M = 10^9 + 7
r(n) = s(n) % M
```

Well come back to that. First, let's look at *f*.

```
f(n) = 2*0 + 2*1 + 2*2 + ... + 2*n
f(n) = 2 * ( 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n )
```

We can take advantage of the following property to obtain a non-iterative formula for `f`:

```
  0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n
= n * ( n + 1 ) / 2
```

Our formula for `f` is now this:

```
f(n) = 2*n + f(n−1)
f(n) = 2*0 + 2*1 + 2*2 + ... + 2*n
f(n) = 2 * ( 0 + 1 + 2 + ... + n )
f(n) = 2 * ( n * ( n + 1 ) / 2 )
f(n) = n * ( n + 1 )
```

Our formula for `s` is now this:

```
s(n=0) = f(n) = 0
s(n>0) = n * ( n + 1 ) + s(n-1)
```

Can we similarly flatten `s`? Yes!

```
s(n) = n * ( n + 1 ) * ( n + 2 ) / 3
```

So we're left with

```
M = 10^9 + 7
r(n) = ( n * ( n + 1 ) * ( n + 2 ) / 3 ) % M
```

---

**Eliminating Large Numbers**

We've eliminated all the looping. But we still have to deal with very large intermediary numbers. Specifically, we have to deal with number three times the size of the input. For example, the calculations for an *n* of 10 involves producing 1,320; for 100, 1,030,200; and for 1,000, 1,003,002,000. This quickly gets out of hand.

To work with manageable numbers, we can take advantage of these properties:

```
  ( x1 + x2 ) % y
= ( ( x1 % y ) + ( x2 % y ) ) % y
= ( ( x1 % y ) + x2 ) % y
```

```
  ( x1 * x2 ) % y
= ( ( x1 % y ) * ( x2 % y ) ) % y
= ( ( x1 % y ) * x2 ) % y
```

So,

```
M = 10^9 + 7

r(n) = ( n( n + 1 ) * ( n + 2 ) / 3 ) % M

# Since the division will always produce an integer
r(n) = ( n * ( n + 1 ) * ( n + 2 ) ) % 3M / 3

mod(a)    = a % 3M
mul(a, b) = ( a * b ) % 3M

r(n) = mul( mul( mod(n), mod(n+1) ), mod(n+2) ) / 3
```

Now, the largest number we need to deal with is n + 2 or ( 3 * ( 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 ) )<sup>2</sup>.

We can even take it a step further.

```
M = 10^9 + 7

mod(a)    = a % 3M
mul(a, b) = ( a * b ) % 3M

r(n) = mul( mul( mod(n), mod(mod(n)+1) ), mod(mod(n)+2) ) / 3
```

Now, the largest number we need to deal with is *n* or ( 3 * ( 10<sup>9</sup> + 7 ) )<sup>2</sup>. This number is very large (0x7CE6,6C6E,38B3,6DB9), but it (barely) fits in a `long`. So if *n* also fits in a `long`, we can eliminate the use of `BigInteger` in favour of `long`!

---

**Code**

```java
int r(long n) {
   const int Mx3 = 3000000021;  // 3 * ( 10^9 + 7 )

   int x =   n       % Mx3;
   int y = ( x + 1 ) % Mx3;
   int z = ( x + 2 ) % Mx3;

   long r = x;
   r *= y; r %= Mx3;
   r *= z; r %= Mx3;
   r /= 3;

   return r;
}
```

The math is verified. This code is untested.

Comment: Fixed problems. (I had accidentally turned multiplication into addition.)